# Bootstrap Modal keep playing audio after video window close in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, browser, bootstrap-modal

The following is the full testing code. The example is running on
http://public.eitan.ac.il/modal/modal-video.html

I am trying to run a youtube video in a pop up window using Modal, but after closing the window, in Firefox the audio keep on playing.  In chrome its working OK.

Any solutions? 10x

```js
var mobileDetect = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

/*
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { $("#myModal #iframeYoutube").attr("src", $("#myModal   #iframeYoutube").attr("src")); 

 }); 
*/

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function() 
   { $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
 })

 function changeVideo(vId){
  var iframe=document.getElementById("iframeYoutube");
  iframe.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId+"?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0";


 if (mobileDetect.mobile()) {
  window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + vId;
 return;
   }

    $("#myModal").modal("show");
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.4.2/mobile-detect.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a href="javascript:changeVideo('e80BbX05D7Y')"><button class="main-btn">Watch</button></a>
  
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">

<div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><a href="#"><span aria-  hidden="true" style="color:white">&times;</span></a></button>
         </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
     <iframe id="iframeYoutube" width="700" height="394" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e80BbX05D7Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>    
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is in your `hidden.bs.modal` function, replace `#` by `_blank`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function() 
        { $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","_blank");
    })
})
```

Comment: GR8!  finally someone who knows what to do :-)